# What's wrong with my template filter?

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I tried to write a simple template filter to round off integers to the nearest half.  If you see my code below you can follow what I'm trying to do.

```
@register.filter
def roundnumber(value):
    if value > 1.75 and value > 2.25
    return 2
    if value > 2.25 and value > 2.75
    return 2.5
    if value > 2.75 and value > 3.25
    return 3
    if value > 3.25 and value > 3.75
    return 3.5
    if value > 3.75 and value > 4.25
    return 4
```

The problem is when I use this inside a template, I get invalidfilter: roundnumber

```
{{ staravg.stars__avg|roundnumber }}
```

Comment: I think your second comparisons should be `<=` rather than `>` shouldn't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the customer template tags or filters, you need to `load` them in the template.

```
{% load customer_templatetags %}
```

NOTE: Make sure the app that contains custom tags/filters are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also make sure the `templatetags` directory have an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: in addition to this make sure you have __init__.py in the templatetags directory inside your app.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do I load the .templatetags.py file?  or the template filter function within the templatetags.py ?

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia templatetags has modules. Right? Specify the module that contains the  filter you defined.

Comment: I put {% load accounts_extras %}, but I'm still getting the same error.  I am thinking the issue is the filter itself, because I have another template filter inside accounts_extras that I am able to use just fine (on another template)